# How add click events to Vue slots?

Tags: vue.js, jsx

The parent element:

```
<solt-div>
  <button slot="trigger">选取文件</button>
</solt-div>
```

The slot component :

```
export default {
  render () {
      return(<div>{this.$slots.trigger}</div>)
  }
}
```

I need to add a click event to `this.$slots.trigger` in order to trigger a function in the `solt-div` component

But this event cannot be added to the outer DIV, because there are other slots

```
<trigger @click="fn"></trigger>
```

Comment: Do you need the click event in `solt-div`, or do you need this event in the parent?

Comment: In element owning `slot="trigger"`  add event   `click`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could just add the event listener `@click="fn"` directly on the button element in the parent

Comment: but, I hope `<solt-div>` other child elements cannot  have `click` event ,

Comment: `click` is handled in `<solt-div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trying to add an event in the render function with `createElement` I came to the solution where you can use a reference to call your function in `solt-div`

**Parent**

```
<solt-div ref="soltDiv">
    <button slot="trigger" @click="$refs.soltDiv.fn()">test</button>
</solt-div>
```

**solt-div**

```
export default {
  render () {
      return(<div>{this.$slots.trigger}</div>)
  },
  methods: {
    fn() {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
},
```